Monitor can’t get signal when graphics card is in computer
I have a relatively old but not very used Radeon rx 5700xt and recently I got it out and used it for a little while before putting another, smaller one, in with it, that worked, but while using a program called mineways, (which is kind of but not super tasking on my CPU), my entire pc froze. I unplugged it and plugged it back in but now when the Radeon rx 5700xt is in the pc, the screen can’t get a signal. If I plug the monitor into the rx 5700xt the screen can’t get a signal, and if I plug the monitor into the other graphics card or directly into the computer, it gets stuck on a screen that says:
Protected by hp sure start
this is what is supposed to displayed on the monitor when the pc is turning on.
I’ve tried using a different kind of cable, plugging it into a different port in the graphics card, and putting the other, smaller card into the spot where the bigger one (the one that isn’t working) was but nothing has had any effect. At first, I thought there could be something physically wrong with the card, but I studied it carefully and didn’t find any sign of damage. Any suggestions on what to do? If you think the graphics card is faulty, is there anything I can do to fix it, I really don’t want to have to buy another one.

The Radeon may be faulty, but we really cannot tell from the details you've given so far. The most convenient thing to do would be to take the computer to a competent local PC technician for analysis. Part of the difficulty is that your post is a "wall of text". Using proper formatting, using more clear and consistent terms to refer to each component of this problem, being generally more precise in your language, may help clarify things.
